# GWT AutoSuggest In JSP

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, autosuggest

I would like to add a GWT autosuggest textbox in JSP.

Could someone provide some insight into this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically GWT is considered a web application framework which is different to a widget framework. Personally I would consider GWT too heavy to just add an autosuggest to a simple web page and instead use something like [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).

Having said that, there's nothing magical about running GWT code. Follow GWT standard module layout and just set up your JSP-page as a [GWT host page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-4/wiki/DevGuideHostPage) where you alter the paths to be absolute to your compiled module.

Comment: I found another article on how to do autocomplete in plain jsp  http://todotomorrow.blogspot.com/2005/06/ajax-autocompletion.html

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how I was able to get a suggest box to work. I make an RPC call to the database while the user is typing.

I agree that you could do something similar in jQuery but why would you when GWT has the widget available?

Hope this helps!

[image]

```
vendorSuggestBox = new SuggestBox(new SuggestionOracle()); //client package

public class SuggestionOracle extends SuggestOracle { //shared package

public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void requestSuggestions(Request request, Callback callback) {
    ItemMovementRemoteServiceAsync service=GWT.create(ItemMovementRemoteService.class);
    service.getVendors(request, new SuggestionCallback(request,callback));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class SuggestionCallback implements AsyncCallback {
    private SuggestOracle.Request req;
    private SuggestOracle.Callback callback;

    public SuggestionCallback(SuggestOracle.Request _req, SuggestOracle.Callback _callback) {
        req=_req;
        callback=_callback;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        callback.onSuggestionsReady(req, new SuggestOracle.Response());
    }

    public void onSuccess(Object result) {
        callback.onSuggestionsReady(req, (SuggestOracle.Response) result);
    }

}



public SuggestOracle.Response getVendors(Request req) { //server package
    Connection db=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    SuggestOracle.Response resp = new SuggestOracle.Response();
    List<Suggestion> suggestions=new ArrayList<Suggestion>();
    int count=0;

    try {
        db=Database.open("ACM0");
        ps=db.prepareStatement(
            " SELECT VE_CD,upper(VE_NAME) VE_NAME" +
            " FROM AP.VE_WEB " +
            " WHERE (VE_NAME NOT LIKE 'AC Moore%') " +
            "   AND (lower(VE_NAME) LIKE ? OR VE_CD LIKE ?)" +
            " ORDER BY VE_NAME");
        ps.setString(1, "%"+req.getQuery().toLowerCase()+"%");
        ps.setString(2, "%"+req.getQuery().toLowerCase()+"%");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next() && count < 25) {
            suggestions.add(new ASuggestion(rs.getString("VE_NAME").trim()+"-"+rs.getString("VE_CD").trim()));
            count++;
        }
        resp.setSuggestions(suggestions);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Database.close(db);
    }
    return resp;
}



public class ASuggestion implements IsSerializable, Suggestion { //shared package model object

private String s;

public ASuggestion(){}
public ASuggestion(String s) {
    this.s=s;
}

public String getDisplayString() {
    return s;
}

public String getReplacementString() {
    return s;
}
```